# Compile SCSS at Runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sproutcore, sass

I have a project whose front-end is written in Sproutcore (1.6) and whose back-end is written in Ruby on Rails.

I've been using SCSS in the Sproutcore project and I now need to allow the client to change their colors on the fly. It doesn't have to be instantaneous, but they should be able to select their color, hit save and re-render the page with the new colors. The problem is, Sproutcore compiles the SCSS at build-time meaning I have no control over it once it's built and released.

As far as I've seen, only LESS can be compiled via Javascript at runtime. Does SCSS have this ability as well? If not, could I hack something together using my Ruby on Rails back-end?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't have multiple css rules which are applied by adding an identifier to your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Javascript version of SCSS.

https://github.com/bmavity/scss-js

However some things like Parameterized Mixins and Functions are not implemented yet.

Comment: +1 - Thanks Thomas. I wound up just porting some of my SCSS to Less and creating a "dynamic stylesheet" served up by Rails, but this looks pretty promising as well.